# How to write in registry from ASP.NET App in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I try to write in the Registry.LocalMachine from an asp.net app. I use the following code, and it works on my development machine :

```
string value = "some value";
RegistryKey clefDeRegistre = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey clefTapi = clefDeRegistre.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\SomeEditor\MySubKey", true);
if (clefTapi != null)
    {
        clefTapi.SetValue("Options", value);
    }
```

But when I try this on my server (Windows Server 2008 R2), it doesn't work.

With the default app pool settings, I received a security exception when trying to write in the registry. So I changed the app pool identity to LocalSystem.

Now I don't receive any exception, but the key isn't modified.

It looks like a problem with [Registry Virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I don't understand how I can disable it.

Comment: *Why*? ASP.NET Web applications run under reduced security privileges for a reason. Why do you want to alter the HKLM hive?

Comment: I have to update the setting for an other app running. This is an old app I can't modify, the only way to modify this setting is by this registry key

Comment: But why from an ASP.NET application? Why not a console program or background Windows Service? That would be more appropriate, and have a much reduced attack-surface.

Comment: Because it will be used from the web page. I'm totally aware of the security issue, and if it's possible I may use a limited user with writing rights on this specific registry key. But first I have to manage to write in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application pool is in 32 bit mode, then the key goes to SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node branch.

Comment: Ok, my appPool had no reason to be in 32 bit mode, I changed it to 64 bit and now it's ok.